# jQuery Mobile Button Size?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, button

I'm trying to make all these buttons the same size, two are bigger because of the text.

Is this possible using the CSS?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is a jQuery Mobile question then button size can be changed by changing this class:

```
.ui-btn {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

**`!important`** is necessary with jQuery Mobile because we need to override default values.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NJ8q4/

Now because you are using a tag buttons (I so it from your previous question) you will need to give it a custom id or class. If you change just .ui-btn you will change every button inside your app. So in the end this CSS will work with this HTML:

#### HTML :

```
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 5</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 4</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 3</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 2</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Level 1</a>                
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Stretch</a>
<a data-role="button" class="custom-btn">Warm up</a>
```

#### CSS :

```
.custom-btn {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

Second working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NJ8q4/1/

Comment: thats awesome thanks its worked!! can i target accordions the same way?

Comment: Tell me which part of accordion you want to change and I will tell you how.

Comment: What if the button contains an icon? How to enlarge the icon with button?